# como colocar required en los inputs de las secciones de las pestañas

Tags: javascript

Hay una forma de colocar de colocar el campo required y que salga ese famoso mensaje
algo como "este campo esta vacio", necesito que al apretar cada vez que se preciona el boton next y este tiene campos vacios en la seccion salga "este campo esta vacio", es decir colocar required
de la otra forma la persona no sabe cual es el campo vacio, ya que son secciones extensas la persona que digita se va a demorar buscando cual es el campo vacio
mientras q si se le coloca required y el foco al campo vacio, la persona que digita no se vaa perder
resumen colocar required en los campos de las secciones y no dejar avanzar si hay un campo vacio en la secciones de cada pestaña

mi intento es en la parte de isAllFieldsFilled() en el for colocar esta linea input.setAtributte('required',true)
pero no aparece los mensajes en los inputs

```js
   class TabbedContent {
  constructor() {
    this.tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".nav li");
    this.sections = document.querySelectorAll(".section");
    this.nextButton = document.querySelector("#nextBtn");
    this.prevButton = document.querySelector("#prevBtn");
    this.current = 0;
  }

  toggleTabs() {
    this.tabs.forEach(function (tab) {
      tab.classList.remove("active");
    });
    this.tabs[this.current].classList.add("active");
  }

  toggleSections() {
    this.sections.forEach(function (section) {
      section.classList.remove("active");
    });
    this.sections[this.current].classList.add("active");
  }

  togglePrev() {
    const method = this.current === 0 ? "add" : "remove";
    this.prevButton.classList[method]("disable");
  }

  toggleNext() {
    const method = this.current === this.tabs.length - 1 ? "add" : "remove";
    this.nextButton.classList[method]("disable");
  }

  goNext() {
    if (this.isAllFieldsFilled()) {
      if (this.current < this.tabs.length - 1) {
        this.current++;
      }
      this.toggleTabs();
      this.toggleSections();
      this.toggleNext();
      this.togglePrev();
    }
  }

  isAllFieldsFilled() {
    const current = this.current;
    const allInputs = [...this.sections];
    const currentSection = allInputs?.[current];
    let shouldGoNext = true;
    if (currentSection) {
      const allInputs = currentSection.querySelectorAll("input");
      for (let input of allInputs) {
        const value = input.value;
       
        if (!value) return false;
      }
    }
    return shouldGoNext;
  }

  goPrev() {
    if (this.current > 0) {
      this.current--;
    }
    this.toggleTabs();
    this.toggleSections();
    this.toggleNext();
    this.togglePrev();
  }
}

const tabbedContent = new TabbedContent();
```

```css
    .container {
              max-width: 600px;
              margin: 0 auto;
              text-align: center;
            }
        
            .section {
              display: none;
            }
        
            .section.active {
              display: block;
            }
        
            ul {
              list-style: none;
              margin: 0;
              padding: 0;
              display: flex;
              justify-content: center;
            }
        
            ul li {
              background: #ccc;
              padding: 10px 15px;
              margin-left: 6px;
              border-radius: 50%;
              cursor: pointer;
              opacity: .5;
            }
        
            ul li.active {
              opacity: 1 !important;
            }
        
            .next,
            .previous {
              padding: 15px 10px;
              border-radius: 6px;
              background: deepskyblue;
              color: white;
              border: 0;
              outline: none;
              cursor: pointer;
              width: 100px;
            }
        
            .next.disable,
            .previous.disable {
              cursor: none;
              opacity: .5;
            }
```

```html
     <div class="container">
              <ul class="nav">
                <li class="active">1</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>3</li>
              </ul>
        
        
  

                <section class="section section-one active">
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required
           minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required
           minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required
           minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required
           minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10">
    
                  </section>
                  <section class="section section-two">
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required
           minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required
           minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required
           minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10">

              </section>
              <section class="section section-three">
                <h2>section 3</h2>
              </section>
        
        
              <button class="previous disable" id="prevBtn" onclick="tabbedContent.goPrev()">Previous</button>
              <button class="next" id="nextBtn" onclick="tabbedContent.goNext()">Next</button>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrías hacer un `focus()` al input vacío (para determinar qué campo está vacío) y romper el ciclo `for` con `break;` para terminar la validación hasta el primer campo vacío que encuentre y no siga validando las demás, ya que sin el `break;`, el ciclo `for` seguirá analizando y hará `focus()` al input vacío final. La validación quedaría así:

```
if (!value) {
  shouldGoNext = false; // establezco el valor que retorna la función a "false".
  input.setAttribute("required", true);
  input.focus();
  break;
}
```

#### Ejemplo:

```js
class TabbedContent {
  constructor() {
    this.tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".nav li");
    this.sections = document.querySelectorAll(".section");
    this.nextButton = document.querySelector("#nextBtn");
    this.prevButton = document.querySelector("#prevBtn");
    this.current = 0;
  }

  toggleTabs() {
    this.tabs.forEach(function (tab) {
      tab.classList.remove("active");
    });
    this.tabs[this.current].classList.add("active");
  }

  toggleSections() {
    this.sections.forEach(function (section) {
      section.classList.remove("active");
    });
    this.sections[this.current].classList.add("active");
  }

  togglePrev() {
    const method = this.current === 0 ? "add" : "remove";
    this.prevButton.classList[method]("disable");
  }

  toggleNext() {
    const method = this.current === this.tabs.length - 1 ? "add" : "remove";
    this.nextButton.classList[method]("disable");
  }

  goNext() {
    if (this.isAllFieldsFilled()) {
      if (this.current < this.tabs.length - 1) {
        this.current++;
      }
      this.toggleTabs();
      this.toggleSections();
      this.toggleNext();
      this.togglePrev();
    }
  }

  isAllFieldsFilled() {
    const current = this.current;
    const allInputs = [...this.sections];
    const currentSection = allInputs?.[current];
    let shouldGoNext = true;
    if (currentSection) {
      const allInputs = currentSection.querySelectorAll("input");
      for (let input of allInputs) {
        const value = input.value;

        if (!value) {
          shouldGoNext = false; // establezco el valor que retorna la función a "false".
          input.setAttribute("required", true);
          input.focus();
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    return shouldGoNext;
  }

  goPrev() {
    if (this.current > 0) {
      this.current--;
    }
    this.toggleTabs();
    this.toggleSections();
    this.toggleNext();
    this.togglePrev();
  }
}

const tabbedContent = new TabbedContent();
```

```css
.container {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.section {
  display: none;
}

.section.active {
  display: block;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul li {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin-left: 6px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

ul li.active {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

.next,
.previous {
  padding: 15px 10px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: deepskyblue;
  color: white;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
}

.next.disable,
.previous.disable {
  cursor: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="active">1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>

  <section class="section section-one active">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required
           minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required
           minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required
           minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required
           minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10">
  </section>

  <section class="section section-two">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required
           minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required
           minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required
           minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10">
  </section>

  <section class="section section-three">
    <h2>section 3</h2>
  </section>

  <button class="previous disable" id="prevBtn" onclick="tabbedContent.goPrev()">Previous</button>
  <button class="next" id="nextBtn" onclick="tabbedContent.goNext()">Next</button>
</div>
```